# what is meant by "failure" in IIS rapid fail protection?

Tags: iis

according to the the IIS documentation the rapid fail protection once activated leads to the deactivation of an application pool if a "failure" occurs. However, I could not find the definition of the "failure" case. In my web application I have a special exception that I would like the IIS to consider it as a "failure".

Does anyone have an idea? Thanks

Comment: I've wondered the same thing.

Comment: This is an excellent question, especially considering that WCF services signal **user** error by throwing an unhandled FaultException.

Answer (score 10):

This appears to have a list, for Server 2003 at least: http://web.archive.org/web/20130511004652/http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc787273(WS.10).aspx

> The WWW service shuts down an application pool whenever a worker
>   process in the application pool fails often enough to equal or exceed
>   the Rapid-Fail Protection (RFP) interval time window (for example:
>   five failures in five minutes). The WWW service detects failure
>   whenever:
>
> - A worker process does not start within the startup time limit.
> - A worker process does not shut down within the shutdown time limit.
> - A worker process shuts itself down because of a fatal error and sends
>     the WWW service an error code.
> - A worker process fails to respond to a ping message.
> - The WWW service detects that a worker process is sending non-standard
>     communications (the worker process may have been taken over).

(updated with archive.org to fix broken link, and replicated detail here)

Comment: Unfortunately this link appears to be dead.

Comment: Thanks, fixed broken link.

Comment: How to force it?

Answer (score 4):

The [documentation](https://www.iis.net/configreference/system.applicationhost/applicationpools/add/failure) for configuring rapid fail protection alludes to a "failure" meaning a worker process crash.

Through experimentation I've noticed that you should expect something like the following in Windows Event Application Logs for a w3wp.exe crash:

> An unhandled exception occurred and the process was terminated.
>
> Application ID: /LM/W3SVC/1/ROOT
>
> Process ID: 2628
>
> Exception: System.SomeUnhandledException

Indeed with rapid fail protection enabled with the default configuration, 5 such events within 5 minutes of each other cause the application pool to stop, and you'll see a further Windows Event Application Log similar to:

> Application pool 'my-test-application-pool' is being automatically
>   disabled due to a series of failures in the process(es) serving that
>   application pool.